# python two list array into a dict with different key?Not just use zip

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas, dictionary

I have two dataframe A and B like this:

```
A:
caption    id    image_id
cat        1        cat.jpg
dog        2        dog.jpg

B:
file_name           id
/image/cat.jpg       1
/image/dog.jpg       2
```

First, I turned them into list by :

```
A.to_dict('record')
B.to_dict('record')
```

And dataframes became:

```
A:
[{'caption':'cat','id':'1','image_id':'cat.jpg'},
{'caption':'dog','id':'2','image_id':'dog.jpg'}]

B:
[{'file_name':'/image/cat.jpg','id':'1'},
{'file_name':'/image/dog.jpg','id':'2'}]
```

Now I want this two list into one dict like below:

```
{'A':[{'caption':'cat','id':'1','image_id':'cat.jpg'},
      {'caption':'dog','id':'2','image_id':'dog.jpg'}],
 'B':[{'file_name':'/image/cat.jpg','id':'1'},
      {'file_name':'/image/dog.jpg','id':'2'}]}
```

I tried zip and dict(A,**B), neither worded.
Thanks so much.

Comment: `{'A': A.to_dict('r'), 'B': B.to_dict('r')}`?

Comment: Alternative: *dict(A = A.to_dict('r'), B = B.to_dict('r'))*